# visual basic difference in dates between two lines in text file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am new to vb express and looking for a way to read two lines in a text file get the difference between then and loop it till the end its a simple clock in clock out system which store each persons clock on and off time in a text file like so

`03/11/2014 09:55:02
03/11/2014 14:55:02
03/11/2014 16:55:02
03/11/2014 19:55:02
04/11/2014 09:00:02
04/11/2014 13:00:00`

I know I use the DateDiff to get the time but I only want them to work out the difference between line 1 and 2 then 3 and 4 and add them all up is it possible to do that without over complicating things?

Answer (score 0):

I guys I have worked it out I have done this by reading the text filed line by line in a loop at the moment I have not put any validation in to show people who have forgot but the basics are there

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "times\08.txt"

    Dim start As DateTime
    Dim finish As DateTime
    Dim total
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

            start = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            finish = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine

             duration = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, start, finish)

            total = duration + total

        Loop

        Label2.Text = total
```